# pandas turn mysql utf-8 into ascii

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, utf-8

I have a mysql utf-8 general ci table but when I load it into a pandas dataframe I get the error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe4' in position 66: ordinal not in range(128) 
  args = ('ascii', ' t...obile Android 1.0 0.0 0.0 ', 66, 67, 'ordinal not in range(128)') 
  encoding = 'ascii'
```

This is for a row where the character ä is in a varchar(255) field.

Why is the data converted to ascii and how can I fix this?

Comment: You seem to be coming from `ASCII`, not `UTF8`.  Ascii has only 1..128, where as `\x84` is 132.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for further discussion.  And dig into what the heck Pandas is doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `python 2.7`
In the beginning of the code , put this

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```

That should do.

Comment: I'm using python 3

Comment: try setting encoding ='utf-8', the error shows that your current encoding is set to ascii